# Android compose recomposition experience

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose

I'm exploring Compose Recomposition with an Experience composable, and I'm a bit confused about its behavior.

In the first code snippet, Experience() was not recomposed after the button click:

```
@Composable
fun Experience() {
    println("Expericence() : Recomposition")

    var j = 5
    var i by remember { mutableIntStateOf(5) }

    Row {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                i++
                j++
                var text  = "i=$i j=$j"
                println(text)
            }
        ) {
            var text  = "i=$i j=$j"
            println("Button() : Recomposition")
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

However, in this second snippet, Experience() is recomposed:

```
@Composable
fun Experience() {
    println("Expericence() : Recomposition")

    var j = 5
    var i by remember { mutableIntStateOf(5) }
    

    Row {
        var text  = "i=$i j=$j"
        Button(
            onClick = {
                i++
                j++
                println(text)
            }
        ) {
            println("Button() : Recomposition")
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? In my understanding, in the second code snippet, only Row and its children should be recomposed, not the entire Experience() composable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest reading the article [What is “donut-hole skipping” in Jetpack Compose?](https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/donut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose). It's exactly your usecase

To answer your question, the recomposition happens because you read the `i` variable inside `Row {}` in your second snippet.

Compose will recompose to the nearest scope. Normally, that'd be `Row`, however, **`Row` is `inline`**, so the nearest scope is your `Experience` composable

Answer (score 0):

Recomposition happens when any part of a `Composable` function changes, then the entire composable is recomposed.

### First code snipped

Even if you extracted the `Text` into a variable, the reference to the text is still within the scope of the `Button`'s lambda, and then it changes.

### Second code snipped

Even if you moved the Text variable outside the `Button`'s lambda it is not a part of the lambda's scope, now, changes to i and j will only trigger recomposition of the `Button` and *its childrens*, not the entire `Experience` composable.

If you want to avoid recomposition you may use `derivedStateOf` to create a derived state that only depends on the specific variables you want.

```
val buttonText by remember(i, j) {
        derivedStateOf {
            "i=$i j=$j"
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I move Text varibale inside Row.
Why all is Recompose and not only Row and child of Row ? (I edit my original  question with this one)

Comment: @Anthone In Jetpack Compose, recomposition happens at the level of the composable function. If any part of a composable function changes, the entire composable is recomposed. When you move the text variable inside the Row in your code, the text variable is still part of the Experience composable function's scope.

Comment: But in first exemple, text is part of lambda of Button and in the second is part of lambda of Row ? I don't see the difference for Experience() method

Comment: The thing is that in the snipped 1 the text variable is declared both inside the onClick lambda of the Button and inside the lambda for Text. However, both declarations are within the scope of the Experience composable function. The recomposition of the entire Experience occurs because changes within the onClick lambda, including changes to text, trigger a recomposition of the entire composable.

Comment: In the first Experience only Button is recompose, so the Button'text show J growing. But in the 2exeperience all is recompse so the button's text j is not growing.